# Getting Foreign Keys in SQLite Database

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

I am trying to read in table schemas from an existing database.

I am reading in all of the tables and columns on each table using the `.tables` and `.columns` command. The `.columns` command returns a variable `PRIMARY_KEY` which lets me know it is a primary key for the table.

My question is how do I know whether a column is a foreign key to another table (and which table it is a foreign key of)?

Comment: The `.tables` command is implemented by the `sqlite3` command-line shell, not by the database itself. There is no `.columns` command.

Answer (score 0):

To get information about the foreign key constraints of a table, use [PRAGMA foreign_key_list](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list).